# Calculating just a single row of dissimilarity/distance matrix

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, distance-matrix

I have a data-frame with 30k rows and 10 features. I would like to calculate distance matrix like below;

gower_dist <- daisy(data-frame, metric = "gower"),

This function returns whole dissimilarity matrix. I want to get just the first row.
(Just distances of the first element in data-frame). How can I do it? Do you have an idea?

Comment: `gower_dist[1,]` will return the first row.  If you are saying you just want to calculate the gower distance for the first row and all other items, you should look at the `gower` package and `gower_dist` function

Comment: You might also be able to get there with `gower_dist <- daisy(data_frame[1,], metric = "gower")`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually it works for the first element. But I tried to calculate distance values for the first N rows. For example;

gower_dist(iris[1:5,], iris) // gower distance for the first 5 rows. but it did not work. Do you have any suggestion about it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to **get the source and extend it**.

I suggest you extend the API by adding a second parameter `y` that defaults to `x`. Then the method should return the pairwise distances of each element in `x` to each element in `y`.

Fortunately, R is GPL open source, so this is easy.

This would likely be a welcome extension, you should submit it to the package authors for inclusion.